# jQuery Mobile Dialogs content not changing

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a list of receipts and a dialog that opens up with details when the receipts are clicked:

```
function showReceipt( urlObj, options, receiptNumber) {
    var pageSelector = urlObj.hash.replace( /\?.*$/, ""),
        $page = $( pageSelector),
        $header = $page.children( ":jqmData(role=header)" ),
        $content = $page.children( ":jqmData(role=content)" ),
        markup='';
    markup += buildReceipt( receiptNumber, markup );
    $header.find( "h1").html( receiptNumber);
    $content.html( markup );
    $page.page();
    $content.find( ":jqmData(role=listview)" ).listview();
    options.dataUrl = urlObj.href;
}
```

html file

```
<div id="receipt" data-role="dialog">
  <div data-role="header"><h1></h1></div>
  <div data-role="content">
  </div>
</div>
```

It works fine when i click on the first receipt, but once i close the dialog and click on another receipt, the details of the first receipt pop up. I've tried various things like:

```
$("#receipt").on("pagehide", function() {
    $("#receipt").jqmRemoveData(':jqmData(role=content)');
});
```

or

```
$("#receipt").on("pagehide", function() {
    $("#receipt").empty();
});
```

and even

```
$("#receipt").on("pagehide", function() {
    $("#receipt").remove();
});
```

but none seem to work. I've tested to see if he variables like receipt number are correct when calling and there's no problem, the correct variables are being passed.

Comment: It would help if you could create a fiddle. My first thought is that more than one dialogs with the same id are created in DOM. Could you check it?

Comment: $(this) has the same result, only the first receipt appears.

fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/MfP8r/

click on branches ----> cebu ----> view sales, then pick one of the two receipts. close it then click the other one, only the info from the first one appears.

according to FF's debugger only one dialog appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the below lines inside the `showReceipt` function:

```
$header = $page.children( ":jqmData(role=header)" ),
$content = $page.children( ":jqmData(role=content)" )
```

with these lines:

```
$header = $page.find( "div:jqmData(role='header')" ),
$content = $page.find( "div:jqmData(role='content')" )
```

and the dialog's content will be updated properly.

The issue is probably related to the fact that [`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) method travels only one level down the DOM tree. On the other side `.find()` can travel down multiple levels.

As you can see in the below HTML code, the `div[data-role='content']` is not a first level child of the page's div `div[id='receipt']`.

```
<div data-role="dialog" id="receipt" data-url="receipt" tabindex="0" class="ui-page ui-body-c ui-dialog ui-overlay-a ui-page-active" style="min-height: 302px;">
  <div role="dialog" class="ui-dialog-contain ui-corner-all ui-overlay-shadow">
    <div data-role="header" class="ui-corner-top ui-header ui-bar-a" role="banner">
      <a data-iconpos="notext" data-icon="delete" href="#" class="ui-btn-left ui-btn ui-btn-up-a ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-icon-notext" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-theme="a" title="Close">
        <span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all">
          <span class="ui-btn-text">
            Close
          </span>
          <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-delete ui-icon-shadow">
            &nbsp;
          </span>
        </span>
      </a>
      <h1 class="ui-title" role="heading" aria-level="1">
        q0001
      </h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" class="ui-corner-bottom ui-content ui-body-c" role="main">
      <p>
        Receipt Number: q0001
      </p>
      <ul data-role="listview" class="ui-listview">
        <li class="ui-li ui-li-static ui-btn-up-c">
          Item: Spaghetti x 3 Total: 150
        </li>
        <li class="ui-li ui-li-static ui-btn-up-c ui-li-last">
          Item: Olive Oil x 1 Total: 1300
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope this helps.